# C# Mysql - Using of locks on database query for async await server

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net, async-await, connection

I have `TcpListener` class and I'm using `async/await` reading and writing.

For this server I have created single database instance where I have prepared all database queries.

But for more then one `TcpClient` I'm keep getting exception:

> An exception of type `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException` occurred
>   in `MySql.Data.dll` but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: There is already an open `DataReader` associated
>   with this `Connection` which must be closed first.

If I understand it correctly there can't be more then one database query at time which is problem with more then one `async` client.

So I simply added locks in my queries like this and everything seems fine.

```
   // One MySqlConnection instance for whole program.

   lock (thisLock)
   {
    var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM logins WHERE username = @user AND password = @pass";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", username);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password);

    var count = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    return count > 0;
}
```

I have also try the method with usings which create new connection for every query as mentioned from someone of SO community but this method is much more slower than locks:

```
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();   // This takes +- 35ms and makes worse performance than locks

        using (MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM logins WHERE username = @user AND password = @pass";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password);

            int count = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            return count > 0;
        }
    }
```

I used Stopwatch to benchmarks this methods and queries with one connection with locks are performed in +- 20ms which is +- only delay of network but with usings it is +- 55ms because of `.Open()` method which takes +- 35ms.

Why a lot of people use method with usings if there is much worse performance? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you [enabled MARS](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/enable-mars/) and set [asynchronous processing](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/asynchronous-processing/) on your connection string?

Comment: @Paulo Morgado I have MySQL not SQL. MySQL does not have MARS as i found on google.

Comment: Instead of the lock why not open another connection?

Comment: @JSteward I have made some tests and opening new connection will take  much more time.

Comment: Isn't `using` just syntactic sugar?

Comment: @Rick James You are usings are sugar for the correct use of IDisposable objects.

Comment: can you give me your connection string use in this program?

Comment: You can use connection pool and with connection pool idle connection will be maintained. For single connection it might seems slower but in actual scenario it will perform better.

Comment: @Shahrooz Ansari Yep I can, lowercase are variables of course. `connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";CHARSET=utf8mb4";`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right, opening connection is a time-consuming operation. To mitigate this, ADO.NET has Connection pooling. Check [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.

If you go on with your performance test and check timings for subsequent connections, you should see that time for `connection.Open()` improves and gets close to 0 ms because connections are actually taken from the Pool.

With your lock implementation, you actually use connection pool with just one connection. While this approach could show better performance within a trivial test, it will show very poor results in highly loaded applications.

Comment: i will try to test it.

Comment: In addition to this it's probably worth adding a mention of using an ORM where this type of work is already built for you (connection pool handling within context instances).

Comment: I agree, a single lock in a highly concurrent application will show terrible performance compared to using ADO.NET connection pooling.

Comment: I can confirm this now. Thank you for got things clear to me.